# need to hide same image at UI

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a web app in PHP
**Small Description:**

- this app is about students,
- their classroom
- individual student can upload their images

but the problem is if a single student uploads same image more than once, at the user end also it is showing the same image more than once.

I want you to help me in the user end so that I can keep a validation kind of thing, that if there is more than one same image, then only one is visible at the user end, and not multiple same images.
the user end code goes like:

```
$getclassrooms=mysql_query("select * from tblclassroom where `ClassId`='$h1' and `IsActive`='1'  and `imagepublish`='1'");
while($hr=mysql_fetch_array($getclassrooms))
{
    $imgname=$hr['Images'];
    $dd=$hr['publishimage'];
    if($imgname=='')$imgname='NoImage.jpg';
?>
```

please note: i want the user to upload same images because the image they insert is linked with their blog comments which means they can use same image for different comments..
but when they view their gallery..i do not want them to view similar images more than once..because then it looks untidy..

I did as you said:
and now my codes looks like:

```
 $getclassrooms=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(Images), publishimage from tblclassroom where `ClassId`='$h1' and `IsActive`='1'  and `imagepublish`='1'");

           while($hr=mysql_fetch_array($getclassrooms))
    {
        $imgname=$hr['Images'];
        $dd=$hr['publishimage'];
        if($imgname=='')$imgname='NoImage.jpg';
    ?>
```

This is working , and not showing similar images..BUT showing an WARNING in the gallery too, with the images..

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /html/classdetails.php on line 967
```

Comment: Tip: use [`mysqli_` functions](http://nl3.php.net/mysqli) instead of [`mysql_` functions](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) for safer interaction with the database

Comment: What does the string inside `$hr['Images']` look like? Just `someImageName.jpg`?

Comment: yes you are right it looks like "imagename.jpg" or "imagename.png" ..

Comment: How does you output look like? Do you `echo` the values inside the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many solutions for this: you can make Images field unique in the database this way a user can't insert the same image name twice, or you can make your select GROUP BY Images like this:

```
$getclassrooms=mysql_query("select * from tblclassroom where `ClassId`='$h1' and `IsActive`='1'  and `publishimage`='1' GROUP BY Images");
```

or you can

```
$getclassrooms=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(Images), publishimage FROM tblclassroom where `ClassId`='$h1' and `IsActive`='1'  and `publishimage`='1'");
```

These may or may not work depending on your DB setup and if you really want the user to upload the same image name twice or not.

Comment: yes i want the user to upload same images because the image they insert is linked with their blog comments which means they can use same image for different comments..
but when they view their gallery..i do not want them to view similar images more than once..because then it looks untidy..

Comment: ok don't use UNIQUE on Images field, just use one of the 2 queries I posted.

Comment: Your 1st query is working..the similar images from blogs are not showing in the gallery, BUT now if any of the image is same to their profile picture ,then the same image is showing TWICE in the Gallery..
How should I solve this problem.

Comment: Please check the editing I have made above in the code.
I did as u said..
but now its showing Warning..

Comment: something wrong with your query, can you show me what you ended up using?

Comment: Hey its working.. i changed this line: while($hr=mysql_fetch_array($getclassrooms)) 
to: while($hr=$getclassrooms)
and this is working...

Answer (score 1):

Ways to to that:

- check if file_exists then you remove the old file and replace the new image file
- check whith md5sum in order to find out uploaded file and the file is being uploaded are 
  same or not.
- you can create a unique name for each student image name. Then you can find out the new uploads